# Service Access Quotas Liferay 7.3

Tags: java, rest, liferay, liferay-7.3

I develop a rest service in Liferay 7.3. Now i want to define a Service Access Quotas about my rest service to limit the invocation.
How can i do this?
What is "Service Signature"?

[image]

Comment: The service signature is the fully qualified classname plus method name

Comment: if my qualified classname is "com.test.TestConsoleRestApplication" and my method is:

POST
Path("/send-pdf")
Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response addEntry(
 Context HttpServletRequest request){

...}

what i can write?